# Avoid index exceptions in some exercise

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, indexoutofboundsexception

Have a question about 2-dimensional arrays. I have an array of dimension n x n, similar to the following.

```
1 5 4 7
2 3 8 0
6 1 0 1
2 9 4 1
```

I need to get all the elements that are to the right of a number. The one on the right, the one on the diagonal up and the one on the diagonal down. For example, for the 3 in the second column, I must get the 4, the 8, and the 0. For the 1 in the first colum, I must get the 5 and 3 (This one does not have a neighbor on the diagonal up). For the 7, it not have a neighbor.

With this method:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
        System.out.print("diagonal-up:" + myArray[i-1][j+1]); //indexOutboundException for the position [0][0] and for all in the last column and first row.
        System.out.print("rigth:" + myArray[i][j+1]); //indexOutboundException for all in the last column
        System.out.print("diagonal-down:" + myArray[i+1][j+1]); //indexOutboundException for all in the last row.
    }
}
```

How can I correct the indexes in this code to avoid index exceptions

Or if you know a better way to solve the exercise, I really appreciate it.

Sorry if the question is silly, but I am learning to work with matrices.

Comment: What do you want to output when there aren't 3 elements to the right?

Comment: @iota, "none" or "there aren't elements".

Answer (score 0):

You can just check if the indexes are in range with an `if` statement.

```
private static String getValue(int[][] arr, int i, int j){
    return i >= 0 && i < arr.length && j >= 0 && j < arr[i].length ? String.valueOf(arr[i][j]) : "no value";
}
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
        System.out.print("diagonal-up:" + getValue(myArray, i-1, j+1) + " ");
        System.out.print("right:" + getValue(myArray, i, j+1) + " "); 
        System.out.println("diagonal-down:" + getValue(myArray, i+1, j+1)); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

````
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++){ 
        if (i-1 >= 0 && j+1 <n)
        System.out.print("diagonal-up:" + myArray[i-1][j+1]); 
        if (j+1 <n)
        System.out.print("rigth:" + myArray[i][j+1]); 
        if (i+1< n && j+1 <n)
        System.out.print("diagonal-down:" + myArray[i+1][j+1]); 
    }
} ```

You can add if conditions to check if the index that is going to be accessed even exists. another small improvement here, would be grouping the if clause for `(j+1 < n )` since it holds for all the three cases :)
````